# "Ghost" images every time I "replay" game

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm creating a game where objects fall from the sky that the user has to catch with a moveable basket image on the bottom. When the object intersects the basket, the object disappears.

I also give the user the option to replay after the first round (the ViewController with the game is reloaded through a storyboard segue). The problem is that the replay seems to keep an invisible "ghost" image/placeholder of the last spot I left the basket at the last time I played the game.

Somehow, the last position of my basket CGRect frame is being saved. Is there some way I can remove this between each game replay?

Edit: By reloading, I mean after a certain point in the game, I initiate a scene transition (I go from one UIViewController to another). Then, I go back to the original UIViewController after pressing a button.

Comment: What do you mean you're "reloading" it through a segue? Are you instantiating the scene again and ending up with multiple running at once or what?

Comment: After a certain point in the game, I initiate a scene transition (I go from one UIViewController to another). Then, I go back to the original UIViewController after pressing a button..and the code fort that UIViewController seems to run from start again.

Comment: You're using a Push segue I presume. You aren't "starting the code again" at all. You're making a new instance of that controller, so now there's two in existence at the same time. If you did that again, you'd have three all stacked up. Every time you segue, the destination gets instantiated and pushed onto one big stack of controllers where the top one is visible.

Comment: Oh, I thought you were pushing twice. If you're pushing then popping to get back, then your state is still there. Push Segues do not get rid of the controller you segued away from. It's just no longer visible. Reinitialize your state in `viewWillAppear:`.

Comment: Ahh, the fact that it's just creating stacks makes sense. So instead of using a push/modal segue, I would configure the button that, when pressed, executes viewWillAppear? And all my code is in viewWillAppear rather than viewDidLoad? (I have a main screen, the game, and then the scoreboard from which I can "restart" the game at)

Comment: ...No. It's very simple, but I'm not very good at explaining. There's a stack and whatever is at the top is what is visible. When you push something on, the thing below it is hidden but still exists. When you pop the thing on top off, the thing below it becomes visible again (and is sent `viewWillAppear` as a result) and the thing on top gets deallocated. So, in the `viewDidAppear` of you game's controller, just set the basket's position to whatever initial position you want so that it gets reset. That way, when the game over controller is popped the game can reset the basket's position.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks a lot for the explanation. I've reset the position of the basket in viewDidAppear, but I still have the same problem--I'll keep working with it. Thanks again.

Comment: If you could zip your code and upload it somewhere with a link here, I'd be glad to look through it and try to sort through it when I have the time.

Comment: Actually, I got it to work based on your suggestions. I really appreciate the offer to look through the code, and thanks for all the help!

Comment: Well, I saw the problem you were having while playing it. Looking through your code, well, it's sort of a mess. I had a hard time following it. You aren't accessing any accessors at all even though you've declared properties (making them utterly pointless) and after a few replays I have a game presented by a gameover screen presented by a game presented by a gameover screen presented by a game presented by a menu. Also, all those globals made my head spin. xD I suggest you look at a good book, like Programming iOS 5, which I'm reading myself. Glad it is working, though. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed giving us the code, so this answer can only be a hot shot.

delete the last position of the basket in `-viewWillApear:`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know what part of the code to give--there's so much. I'll try to include what I feel is relevant in an edit. As for your suggestion, is this what you mean?: -(void)viewWillAppear{
        [basketView removeFromSuperview];
}. Thanks for the help!

Comment: you will have to give us more code. this does not show anything about baskets state.

Comment: I cant tell you, what parts you will ahve to give, as I have no idea, how your code looks like. anything regarding the basket.

Comment: Ahh, I got it to work anyway with this viewWillAppear method. Thanks for the help you were able to give